# Java Как перебрать массив по несколько значений

Tags: java, массивы

Есть массив например:

```
int [] x = {10,3,15,17,5,30,21,41,90,115,1,3,6};
```

необходимо пройтись по нему с конца и вычислить Максимум через каждые 3 числа :

```
"1,3,6" = 6
"41,90,115" = 115
...
```

До сюда дошел

int [] x = {10,3,15,17,5,30,21,41,90,115,1,3,6};

```
    int max = 0;
        for (int i = x.length - 1; i > 0;  i--) {
            if(max < x[i]) {
                max =x[i];
                System.out.println(max);
            }
```

Как по 3 числа, так и не могу понять...

Comment: А с десяткой что делать?

Comment: Да, это не важно, мне принцип понять... Она не будет учавствовать

Comment: Уже написали, правильное решение

Answer (score 1):

```
int max = 0;
for (int i = x.length - 1; i - 2 >= 0;  i = i - 3) {
  max = x[i];
  if (x[i - 1] > max)
    max = x[i - 1];
  if (x[i - 2] > max)
    max = x[i - 2];
  System.out.println(max);
}
```

```js
var x = [10,3,15,17,5,30,21,41,90,115,1,3,6];
for (var i = x.length - 1; i - 2 >= 0;  i = i - 3) {
  var max = x[i];
  if (x[i - 1] > max)
    max = x[i - 1];
  if (x[i - 2] > max)
    max = x[i - 2];
  console.log(x[i - 2], x[i - 1], x[i], "=>", max);
}
```